# Unable to access plugins manager in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to access the plugins manager but keep getting this error [image]

I am using apache-jmeter-5.4.1, and have manually download jmeter-plugins-manager-1.6.jar, and put it into the lib/ext folder. However, I am still encounter this issue.

Answer (score 1):

`unable to find valid certification path to requested target` error means that JMeter's Plugins Manager cannot securely connect to its [plugins repository](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/#Plugins-Sources-Configuration), the address is [`https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/repo/)

It means that the certificate has expired, it's not trusted by CA, there is a mismatch between issuer and dns address, etc. As there are thousands of the JMeter Plugins Manager users and only you reported this issue in last 12 hours I think it is **your** problem, like you're working for a shitty company which is using [MITM certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) for monitoring your networking activity and JMeter Plugins Manager complains that the certificate should not be in the chain.

You can diagnose the issue by either adding `javax.net.debug=all` line to [JMeter's *system.properties* file](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) or using external tool like [openssl](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-ssl-communications-from-unix-shell-prompt.html)

If you don't care about the root cause in the slightest and OK with your employer or ISP or government monitoring your traffic given you can open the plugins repository URL in the browser - you can just [obtain the certificate](https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2), install it into the [truststore](https://www.baeldung.com/java-keystore-truststore-difference) and configure JMeter to use the truststore.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your proxy setting to access the internet.
You have downloaded & set up plugin manager but plugin manager is unable to access repo via your current internet proxy setting.
I hope you have switched off your recording settings(localhost:8080 set up to record).

Comment: hi Prateek, thanksfor the message. I am still having problem get this to work.

Comment: (1) my proxy is like below:

Comment: *.local, 169.254/16